# PyDev doesn't auto-complete my imported modules

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

I have Eclipse 4.7.3 with PyDev installed. When I import modules from another directory (or any for that matter) pydev doesn't show a warning that it can't find the import but it doesn't do autocomplete for functions within that import. 
Ex `import DataDefines as df` and then when using it like `df.INSERTFUNCTIONHERE` it doesn't give any usefull suggestions for functions found in that file. When I run it, it grabs the imports fine but I want to be able to auto-complete for syntax and spelling reasons. What could be going wrong? I have configured my python interpreter which helped make the program actually run and I have modified settings in Preferences -> PyDev -> Code Completion but now I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Are your sources under a source folder?

Have you tried following the getting started?

http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html

If you're not able to figure out from that, please provide a screenshot of your pydev package explorer showing the modules you have and the actual issue on the completion.